# Booting programs from an Intel Edison board

Tags: arduino, embedded, intel-edison

I just bought an [Intel Edison Breakout Board Kit](http://www.arduino.cc/en/ArduinoCertified/IntelEdison) with the Grove Starter Kit Plus I want to write a program which gives the board an IP address, checks for a temperature in a room and if that temperature is exceeded it turns a LED on. I can check what's going on with a RGB display. When I connect the USB OTG port to the my laptop the wifi connection is perfectly detected, the IP address is perfectly received and the temperature control works fine. The program works as I ask for. Now the questions. I would like to execute the same program unplugging the USB connection, so I would like to make this board independent from PC, like if it is a standing alone device 
 
1) if I upload this working program in the board, unplugging the USB and of course giving just the power supply through the jack on the breakout board it does not work anymore and stops on the message "preparing network connection...". But Intel Edison has an integrated wifi module and I really can't understand why it is not able to establish an internet connection anymore without the help of the USB connection with my laptop. What's wrong with it? how to boot and execute this program just with the power supply? This is the setup function() of my program, we don't reach the loop() one so I will not post it

```
void setup()
{  
// ------ LCD IN ACTION ------ //  
// set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
lcd.begin(16, 2);

// setting the color for the connection
lcd.setRGB(colorR, colorG, colorB);
lcd.print("preparing network connection...");

// scroll 40 positions (string length) to the left
// to move it offscreen left: 
for (int positionCounter = 0; positionCounter < 40; positionCounter++) 
{
    // scroll one position left:
    lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
    // wait a bit:
    delay(350);
}


// ------ SERIAL CONNECTION ------ //

// opening the serial connection
//    Serial.begin(9600);      // initialize serial communication


// ------ SETTING I/O PINS ------ //

pinMode(potentiometer, INPUT);      // angle sensor's pin for input.

pinMode(12, OUTPUT);      // set the blue LED pin mode
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);      // set the red LED pin mode
pinMode(pinLed, OUTPUT);  // set the green LED pin mode


// ------ WIFI CONNECTION CONTROLS ------ //

// check for the presence of the wifi shield:
if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) 
{
//        Serial.println("WiFi shield not present"); 
    while(true);        // don't continue
} 

// check firmware version
String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
//    if( fv != "1.1.0" )
//        Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");


// ------ WIFI CONNECTION ------ //

// attempt to connect to Wifi network:
while (status != WL_CONNECTED) 
{ 
//        Serial.print("Attempting to connect to Network named: ");
//        Serial.println(ssid);                   // print the network name (SSID);

    // connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:    
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    // wait 3 seconds for connection:
    delay(3000);
}

server.begin();                           // start the web server on port 70
printWifiStatus();
```

where

```
void printWifiStatus() {

  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  //  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  //  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  colorR = 255;
  colorG = 180;
  colorB = 0;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setRGB(colorR, colorG, colorB);
  lcd.print(WiFi.SSID());
  delay(3000);

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
//  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
//  Serial.println(ip);
  colorR = 0;
  colorG = 255;
  colorB = 0;
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.setRGB(colorR, colorG, colorB);
  lcd.print(ip);
  delay(3000);
  /*
  delay(5000);
  colorR = 180;
  colorG = 255;
  colorB = 255;
  lcd.setRGB(colorR, colorG, colorB);
  lcd.noDisplay();
  */

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  //  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  //  Serial.print(rssi);
//  Serial.println(" dBm");
  // print where to go in a browser:
  //  Serial.print("To see this page in action, open a browser to http://");
  //  Serial.println(ip);
}
```

2) always about the execution of pre-loaded programs: if I load the default blink program of ArduinoIDE, unplug the USB and just give the power supply it works perfectly [this one is correctly self-booted, yes] but if I upload the same program with a Serial.begin() and a Serial.print("Arduino blinking") it doesn't work anymore without the USB connection to my laptop [this is why I commented the Serial stuff before]. Is it because the board is so smart to detect that in the first case the serial connection is not really happening?

3) last question about program storage: when I compile a program with the arduino IDE it gives me the percentage of memory used related to the available one for programs

```
Sketch is using 103.266 byte (1%) of program memory. The limit is 10.000.000 byte
```

but Intel Edison has a 4GB eMMC so why there are only 10MB available to programs? in which memory are the programs uploaded?

Thanks in advance to those who will try to help

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know how can I do to check where is it stored?

You can check your files on serial communication terminal. If you have possible directories that your file could be in, you can use linux commands like:

`cd directory` and `ls`

or even you can 'search' the file if you know the name. You may want to check [this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-find-and-locate-to-search-for-files-on-a-linux-vps).

or you can use SCP, FTP client programs like [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) to see the files on your Edison.

Answer (score 0):

> if I upload this working program in the board

Are you sure that your program is flashed into persistent memory ? I do not know this board. In most cases this kind of problems comes when your program is only transferred to RAM memory, but not stored in Flash.

> Sketch is using 103.266 byte (1%) of program memory. The limit is
>   10.000.000 byte

10MB RAM, or Flash memory ?

As far as I understand you use Arduino + Edison ?

Which board 10MB limit corresponds to ? Sketch is using 103.266 byte: is it RAM or Flash ?

Comment: Thank you @Bartlomiej! As I wrote before I don't know in which memory the program is uploaded. I just write the code in the Arduino IDE and I upload it to the board with the arrow [upload] icon. Do you know how can I do to check where is it stored? for the second quotation, again, it is not specified. I just pasted the english translation of Arduino IDE message. To be clear my working configuration is [this one](http://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/ArduinoCertified/Intel_Edison_Kit_Front.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Try typing these commands in through putty

```
ifconfig usb0 down
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig usb0 up
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

that might do it